# why am i getting a syntax error in my logitech g lua script?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

i have been learning lua to code an auto clicker for my g903 that works when the right mouse button is held and can be toggled with the capslock key.
any help or insight would be appreciated

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)=true
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock"=true then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)=true then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)=true then
                    repeat
                        PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
                        Sleep(math.random(20,80))
                    until IsMouseButtonPressed(1)=false
                end
            until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)=false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the error as well?

Comment: What do you think `function OnEvent(event,arg)=true` means?

Comment: Also, do you know the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: You can not simultaneously simulate virtual LMB `PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)` and monitor physical LMB state `IsMouseButtonPressed(1)`

Answer (score 2):

`function OnEvent(event,arg)` is the beginning of a function definition. You cannot assing true here as attempted in `function OnEvent(event,arg)=true`. This will give an error for an unexpected symbol near '='. Lua cannot make sense of this.

In `if IsKeyLockOn("capslock"=true then` you're missing a cosing parenthesis. After adding that it is still incorrect as for all the following lines:

```
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")=true then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)=true then
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)=true then
```

you get an error 'then' exepected near '='

```
until IsMouseButtonPressed(1)=false
until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)=false
```

you get an error '' expected near 'until'

You are confusing the assignment operator `=` with the equality operator `==`.

See [Relational Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.4) and [Assignment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3)

As a side note, these functions are already returning true or false.

You don't have to explicitly check wether the return value equals true. There are only two possible outcomes. `true == true -> true` or `false == true -> false`. So you can use the return value directly and simply write `if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then`.

If you want to do someting in the `false` case it is common practice to simply negate the return value. `not false -> true`

In this case you simply write if not `if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then` instead of `if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) == false then`.

Comment: In addition, `IsMouseButtonPressed` etc return a boolean. Comparing a boolean with `true` effectively does nothing, so you can remove all `== true`. Similar with `== false`, it's more common to use [`not`](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) instead.

Comment: ive fixed the code as you suggested and it shows no errors now and seems to "work" according to ghub but the script still isnt registering clicks.

Comment: CURRENT CODE IS AS FOLLOWS;

`EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
                        Sleep(math.random(20,80))
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end`

Comment: please ask a new question